# Why declare the variables of public properties on the interface with the property declarations?

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking at this code below and trying to figure out which of the two of us... (me, or the person who wrote it) doesn't know what they're doing.

Why did he/she declare properties, then declare matching variables as well?
I can't ask the person because this project is inherited from a group long gone.

```
@interface LayerList : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
    {
        UITableView *tvList;
        ArcGisViewController *mapController;
        NSArray *fileList;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tvList;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) ArcGisViewController *mapController;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *fileList;

    -(void)visibleSwitchValueChanged:(id)sender;

    -(IBAction) Cancel;
@end
```

Comment: This was the usual way in a day when you had to `synthesize` the properties manually.

Comment: @vadian  That was before my time with ObjC.  So you would declare variables publicly on the interface, instead of privately in the implementation file?

Comment: There was a short period of time where you had to declare all properties in the Interface but this was before ARC has been introduced.

Comment: @vadian - If you move your comment to an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Bottom line, not only do you not put these ivars in the public interface, but you generally don’t declare ivars at all any more, except for very special cases. You generally don’t even need `@synthesize` declarations any more, either. The only time you have to worry about this sort of thing is where you manually implement accessor methods. By the way, the default ivars the are synthesized for you generally bear the an underscore prefix (e.g. `_tvList`, to help avoid confusion with the similarly named property, `tvList`).

Comment: “Why did he/she declare properties, then declare matching variables as well?” ... Needless to say, the author probably was writing Objective-C back before auto-synthesizing of ivars existed (or was learning from old code snippets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the usual way in a day when you had to `synthesize` the properties manually before auto-synthesizing was introduced.

Comment: Actually, this has nothing to do with ARC even if it was implemented around the same time.

Comment: @Sulthan My comment *before ARC has been introduced* was only related to the point in time. I changed the phrasing.

Comment: The answer is only partially correct, in Objective-C you can have iVar's and properties with the same name, regardless you want to synthesize or not. Without seeing the implementation file we can only assume that the names match due to synthetization.